# Select IN query cosmos DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

How to write a select IN query in cosmos db/document db? Something similar to this

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name IN (value1, value2, ...)
```

I am using Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core nuget package.

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at [`IN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-keywords#in) and [CONTAINS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-contains)?

FOR EX,

```
  SELECT *
    FROM Families
    WHERE Families.id IN ('AndersenFamily', 'WakefieldFamily')
```